# Is there any difference in meaning between "after five minutes" and "five minutes later"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Is there any difference in meaning between *after five minutes* and *five minutes later*? For example:

> Yesterday I got to work and **after five minutes** I started working?
>
> Yesterday I got to work and **five minutes later** I started working.

If there is no difference at all, then which one is more common?

Comment: To me, 'after five minutes' conveys more of the idea of _waiting_ for something to happen. "After five minutes I managed to get the car started."

Comment: Some contexts require one or the other. **They arrived five minutes after the plane had left.** **Five minutes later, the bomb exploded.**

Comment: What if said "after five minutes the bomb exploded", wouldn't it mean the same?